# eliminate extra spaces in VARCHAR columns

Tags: db2

In a table, I have an ID column defined as BIGINT(8) and one VOUCHER column that is VARCHAR(100). No matter the actual length of the value in that field, the SQL always returns a full length value, which can be cumbersome in CLI, specially when selecting more fields.

Here is a sample of what I'm getting

```
ID                   VOUCHER                                                                                               
-------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                   
               26462 7083d8374831148f9e2271741529ee37                                                                                                                                                 
               26624 9170220e6971c2414613d0a69b420156                                                                    
               26625 b75d12847a24981d36f7bfcd58e8a230
```

I tried `TRIM` / `LTRIM` / `RTRIM` functions, but without success.

What can I use to get something along these lines, at least for display purposes:

```
ID     VOUCHER                           
------ --------------------------------
26462  7083d8374831148f9e2271741529ee37
26464  9170220e6971c2414613d0a69b420156
26465  b75d12847a24981d36f7bfcd58e8a230
```

Comment: In SQL Server, I get around this by `CAST`ing the output to the appropriate max length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @JNK's comment, `select cast(trim(id) as varchar(6)) as id, cast(trim(voucher) as varchar(32)) as voucher, auth from my_table` does the job.

Comment: Now how do I accept @JNK's suggestion?

Comment: He has to convert his comment to an answer.

Comment: @MariusButuc Just self-accept.  I was guessing since I don't use DB2!